# Could not fetch JSON URL and some error show below, App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://)

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, info.plist

### ERROR##

```
2016-06-09 12:31:56.252 chamber_of_commerce[2202:69165] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

firstly project create on Xcode 5.2 and today reopen xcode7.2. this problem is not so?

I Used Xcode7.2 and used all methods but did not solve my problem. please help me how to use web services in my project. I'm trying many times but did not work any methods. please solve my problem.

```
I used non-lazy method, but it didn't work. Followings are my tries.

first,
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>www.edutimeapp.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

```
  and second,
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>www.edutimeapp.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

```
Finally, I used lazy method.
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: Please have a look on this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http

Comment: @neha used all methods, but did not work and same error show.

Comment: firstly project create on Xcode 5.2 and today reopen xcode7.2. this problem is not so?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.edutimeapp.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Add,

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <false/>
```

`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` must be `false` because it disallows all **insecure** connection, but exceptions list allows connection to some domains without **https**.

Comment: I am trying your code but same error show. how to solve error?